# How can I read the Library file used in BIRT report?

Tags: birt

Can any one guide /help me ..How to read a BIRT report and get the Library and dataset used in the Report.

I tried using all different Parsers to read the file .every time i am getting 
 org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory --ERROR.

Later I tried Apache Xerces - DOM Parser 
When i used the Apache Xerces - DOM Parser  i can parse the report  which is in XMl format.But i cannt able to read it...Throwing error.

Need help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems you are not using BIRT to run oder edit the report design. Your question is tagged as birt, but obviously it is not a question regarding BIRT usage.

Comment: My question Is about BIRT Report only.I need to parse and read BIRT report design file.Wat the library used and dataset uses in .rpt design file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like this before. You can use standard parser emdeeded in jdk along with XPath

1. `javax.xml.parsers.*`
2. `javax.xml.xpath.*`
3. `org.w3c.dom.*`

Below is a sample code, if you read carefully I think you'll get the idea.

```
    //this path contains dataset start
    public static final String RPTLIBRARY_XPATH_DATA_SET_NODE_START = "//library/data-sets/oda-data-set[@name='";

    //this path contains SQL in rptlib
    public static final String RPTLIBRARY_XPATH_QUERYTEXT_NODE_END = "']/xml-property[@name='queryText']";

    public Document getXMLAsDocumentObject(InputStream is) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        doc.normalize();

        return doc;
    }

    public Node getNode(Element element, String xPath) throws XPathExpressionException{
        _log.debug(xPath);

        XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(xPath);
        Node tableNode = (Node) xPathExpression.evaluate(element, XPathConstants.NODE);

        return tableNode;
    }

    public NodeList getNodeList(Element element, String xPath) throws XPathExpressionException{
        _log.debug(xPath);
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(xPath);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(element, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        return nodeList;
    }
```